# Sets which are not fixed by any non-identity isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field (finite or infinite but big enough). I am looking for a subset $W$ of $V$ such that for any bijective but non-identity linear map $T: V \longrightarrow V$, $T(W) \not = W$. Is it always possible to find such a set ?

Comment: I'm going to have to echo the question raised in comments below: big enough for *what*?

Comment: @ToddTrimble Big enough to avoid small fields. Consider $\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus\Bbb{Z}_2$ over $\Bbb{Z}_2$. Then a calculation shows that there is no such $W$ in this case. I was hoping for larger fields the answer is positive.

Comment: So, the question is: is there a cardinal number $\kappa$ such that for all fields $F$ of cardinality $\kappa$ or greater and all vector spaces $V$ over $F$, there exists a subset $W \subset V$ such that for all non-identity linear automorphisms $f: V \to V$, we have $f(W) \neq W$?

Comment: @ToddTrimble Yes. I believe my question asks for the same.

Comment: indeed, I was confirming that this was your question. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: V = the real numbers as a 1-dimensional real vector space W = the positive integers 1, 2, 3... Am I missing something? By "subset" do you actually mean "subspace"?

Comment: none: You are missing the word "always", meaning "for every finite-dimensional vector space" over the given field.

Comment: Also, it is easy to see that a subspace, other than 1 trivial example, could not possibly fit the requirement

Answer (score 5):

*I will modify the construction of A.B. a bit; so it works for fixed field and arbitrary dimension of $V$.*

Choose a basis $e_i$ in $V$ and consider the set $W$ 
which includes $e_i$, $2{\cdot} e_i$ for each $i$ and $e_i+2\cdot e_j$ for $i<j$.

Note that if $f(W)=W$ then the basis goes to basis
(these are the only elements $w\in W$ such that $2\cdot w\in W$).
Further note that the order of basis survives; i.e., $W$ is the set you want.

Comment: What if the characteristic is 2?

Comment: Well, instead of $2$ one has to use an element $a\ne 0, 1, 1/a$.  This can be done in any field except $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Maybe I am missing something, But how do you conclude that for any non-identity automorphism $f$, $f(W)\not = W$ ??

Comment: Why $W$ is THE set ?

Comment: @Sally He shows that if there is an automorphism of $V$ which fixes $W$, then $e_i$ must go to some $e_j$: this follows since if $e_i$ goes to $2e_j$ it would force $4e_j$ to be in $W$ (I guess he assumes $4\neq 1$), and if $e_i$ goes to $e_j+2 e_k$ then it would force $2 e_j+4 e_k$ to be in $W$. Similar arguments shows that the $e_i$ cannot go to $e_j$ if $j>i$: pick maximal such $i$, so $e_j$ goes to $e_k$ with $k<j$, therefore $e_i+2e_j$ goes to $e_j+2e_k$, a contradiction. So this automorhpism is the identity.

Comment: So, Anton answered the question positively for any fields except two. For the two-element field, the answer is obviously negative. What about the only remaining case?

Comment: @AntonKlyachko I tried to answer your question below. Hopefully I didn't make another mistake.

Comment: @Anton Klyachko: Sorry I do not see why "For the two-element field, the answer is obviously negative."

Comment: Anton, in two-dimensional space, there are only three non-zero vectors and we can choose nothing (singletons are obviously bad and two-elements subsets are no better as their complements are singletons).

Comment: @AntonKlyachko I think he means it's not obvious the answer is negative in a large dimension.

Comment: @A.B., yes, this is nontrivial. But I understand the question as: find all fields such that, for any f.d. space over this field, blah-blah-blah.

Comment: @AntonKlyachko I guess you are right, but analyzing the case of large dimension over the 2-element field seems to be very interesting and far less trivial

Comment: @AntonKlyachko I've added a followup question for our friend $F_2$ http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138672/sets-from-f-2n-which-are-not-fixed-by-any-non-identity-isomorphism

Answer (score 4):

If the cardinality of the field is much larger than the dimension of $V$ then:
Start with a basis $B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and then take the set $S=B\cup \{\alpha_1v_1,\alpha_2v_2,...,\alpha_nv_n\}$ (I guess in finite characteristic you need to choose the scalars carefully).

If a linear transformation $T$ fixes $S$, then for some $v_i$, $T(v_i)\in\{\alpha_iv_i,v_j,\alpha_jv_j\}$.

Therefore, $T(\alpha_iv_i)\in\{\alpha_i^2v_i,\alpha_iv_j,\alpha_i\alpha_jv_j\}$. If $\alpha_i^2\neq 1$, $\alpha_i\neq \alpha_j$ and $\alpha_i\alpha_j\neq 1$ for all $i,j$ then this seems enough.

EDIT: (I'll modify Anton Petrunin's construction a bit to answer Anton Klyachko's question about $F_3$)

For the field of 3 elements, assuming $n>2$: Choose a basis $e_i$ and take $W$ which includes $e_i,2e_i$ for each $i$, $e_i+2e_j$ for $i<j$, and $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} e_i$. Assume by contradiction that $T$ is a non-trivial automorphism of $V$ which fixes $W$.

If $T(e_i)=e_j+2e_k\in W$ then $j<k$ so $T(2e_i)=e_k+2e_j\notin W$, a contradiction. If $T(e_i)=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} e_i$ then $T(2e_i)=2\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} e_i\notin W$. So for each $i$, $T(e_i)\in\{e_j,2e_j\}$.

Since if $e_i\neq e_j$ then $T(e_i)\neq \alpha T(e_j)$, we get that $T(\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} e_i)=\Sigma_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_j e_j\in W$ with $\alpha_j\in\{1,2\}$. Therefore, all the $\alpha_j$s must be 1.

That means that $T$ makes a permutation of the $e_i$s, and we get a contradiction by Anton's explanation.

Comment: **A serious problem:** Suppose $n$ (the dimension) is larger than the cardinality of the field. Then the assumption $\alpha_i \not = \alpha_j$ can not hold.

Comment: But you said the field is big enough

Comment: Right, But the field is fixed and $V$ can have any dimension.

Comment: So what does big enough mean?

Comment: That means big enough, like $2^{1000000}$ but $V$ can have dimension $2^{1000000} + 1$.

Comment: I was more interested in what "enough" means, but I'll take it as arbitrarily large.

Comment: What is $S$ in the begining of part II ?

Comment: "we must therefore have either $\alpha_iv_i$ or $\alpha_jv_j$ in $S$". Why? We may take some combination, e.g., $v_i+\alpha v_j$...

Comment: You are right, I'll rethink. But I believe the answer will still be no.

Comment: You are right about $F_3$. So, to answer the question "Find all fields..." it remains to analyse the two-dimensional space over the three-element field. This can be done by brute force surely. But to answer the question "Find all spaces..." we have to deal with almost all spaces over the two-element field...

Comment: OK, I've just checked all possibilities for $\mathbb{F}_3^2$, and none of them work; there is no such set.  It doesn't take long because you can assume there are at most 4 non-identity elements; and since 2 of them will have to be linearly independent, you can take 2 of them to be the standard basis and then you're dealing with at most 2 more elements. This makes it easy to enumerate the possibilities (especially since there's an obvious symmetry swapping $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that works for all fields with more than $2$ elements. 
I will denote the underlying field by $F$ and assume that $|F|>2$. 
The idea is to use an induction to construct a solution
for $n$-dimensional spaces. I will consider $F^n$ as a linear subspace of 
$F^{n+1}$ by using the embedding $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_n,0)$. 
Assume that we have a subspace $W_n$ of $F^n$ that is a solution, and 
consider the subspace $W_{n+1}$ of $F^{n+1}$ defined as the union of $W_n$
with the set of all vectors $(x_1,\dots,x_n,1)$ with $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \neq 0$.

I contend that, unless $n=1$ and $|F|=3$, the subset $W_{n+1}$ is a solution for the 
space $F^{n+1}$. Indeed, let $f$ be an automorphism of $F^{n+1}$ that leaves $W_{n+1}$
invariant. Unless $n=1$ and $|F|=3$, one checks that the affine hyperplane $\mathcal{H}$ with equation $x_n=1$ is the sole non-linear affine hyperplane of $V$ such that 
$\mathcal{H} \setminus W$ contains at most one point. Thus, $\mathcal{H}$ is stable under $f$. It follows that $f$ fixes $(0,\dots,0,1)$, as it is the only point of $\mathcal{H} \setminus W$, and on the other hand the translation vector space $H$ of $\mathcal{H}$ - associated with the equation $x_n=0$ - is stable under $f$. By induction, $f$ is the identity on $H$. As $f$ is linear, one concludes that it is the identity.

If $|F|>3$, this method yields a solution in every situation as one can start from 
$W_1:=\{1\}$. If $|F|=3$, there is no solution for $n=2$ as was noted by Harry Altman, 
but there is one for $n=3$: one sets $\mathcal{H}:=\{(x_1,x_2,1) \mid (x_1,x_2) \in F^2\}$ and
 $W_3=\{(1,0,0)\} \cup (\mathcal{H} \setminus \bigl\{(0,0,1),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}\bigr\}$. 
Then, one can check that $W_3$ is a solution for $F^3$: 
indeed, one sees that $\mathcal{H}$
is the sole affine hyperplane of $F^3$ such that $|\mathcal{H} \setminus W_3|=3$.
Let $f$ be an automorphism of $F^3$ that leaves $W_3$ invariant. Then, $f$
also leaves $\mathcal{H}$ invariant, and it must induce an affine automorphism of 
it that permutes the three points $(0,0,1)$, $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1)$, 
and it must induce an automorphism of $F^2$ that fixes $(1,0,0)$ (as $F^2$
is the translation vector space of $\mathcal{H}$).
Note that $f$ must fix $(0,0,1)+(1,0,1)+(0,1,1)=(1,1,0)$, 
whence $f$ induces the identity on $F^2$. It follows that the restriction of $f$
to $\mathcal{H}$ is a translation, and from there it is easily checked that 
this translation is the identity by using the fact that $f$ leaves $\{(0,0,1),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$ invariant. Thus, $f$ is the identity and $W_3$ is a solution, as claimed. 
With the above method, one obtains a solution for all $n\geq 3$ if $|F|=3$.

Comment: [Oops, messed up earlier.] This doesn't seem to work when $F=\mathbb{F}_3, n=2$, since then, if I'm understanding right, $W=\{(1,0), (1,1), (2,1)\}$, and the linear transformation swapping $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ preserves it.

Comment: Hm -- something must be even more wrong, because so far as I can tell, there is no such set in that case.  (I notice that in your proof, in the case I've given, the "...is the sole affine hyperplane..." step seems to fail...)